# Иск чукчей на Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова

Tags: лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов

Многие участники форума, наверняка, знают об этой истории. Чукчи подали в суд на составителей Большого толкового словаря под редакцией С. А. Кузнецова.Поводом возмущения послужило то, что в издании 1998 года слово "чукча" имеет два значения. Помимо обычного, в словаре есть также формулировка, что чукча - это наивный, ограниченный человек. В иске отказали.

> А что вы думаете по этому поводу? Имел ли словарь право включать такое определение?

Comment: Ну, такая же история была, как говорили, с Татарстаном, когда они, якобы, подали жалобу на поговорку "незваный гость хуже татарина".  В результате обсуждения поговорку изменили на "незваный гость **лучше** татарина".

Comment: А кто изменил - они? В наших словарях по-прежнему старая поговорка. Это же глупо менять поговорки, пословицы.

Comment: @VictorBazarov это байка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь не должен был этого делать. Отождествление принадлежности к одному из этносов с умственными способностями человека - из области анекдотов, где это традиционно допустимо. В языковой практике (за пределами старосоветской серии анекдотов "про чукчу" - в единственном числе) такого нет: это слово произносится не в нарицательном смысле, а всегда связано с этническим персонажем из старого анекдота (например, есть присказка "чукча не читатель, чукча - писатель"). Если же кто-то из составителей где-то слышал это слово в качестве **прямого синонима** того, что привёл в словарной статье, ему следовало приберечь подобное значение для *словаря сленга* - тогда он поступил бы профессионально. Не заметившему это редактору (не знаю, правда, какую позицию он занимал в суде) можно посочувствовать: вышло что-то вроде клеветы на русский язык.

Comment: Александр, ну ведь анекдот - это тоже язык, фольклорный. Вы совершенно правильно заметили: из областей анекдота; а анекдоты являются непосредственной часть- культуры, фольклора.

Comment: Кстати, в новом издании, определение немного измени. Было: наивный, ограниченный человек, стало: наивный ***простодушный*** человек. Т.е. немного смягчили категоричность определение.

Comment: Серж, дело не столько в политкорректности, сколько в способе употребления слова: это не совсем синоним такого человека - скорее, фольклорный персонаж, к которому косвенно отсылают, намекая на чью-то неосведомлённость или оторванность от городской цивилизации. А при старых и новых формулировках человек, решивший воспользоваться словарём практически, будет просто называть кого-то "чукчей". Возможно, соотв. соавтор незнаком с сюжетами тех анекдотов, хотя от кого-то похожее слышал.

Comment: Александр, вряд ли можно считать второе значение синонимом первого. Это насколько надо быть неосведомленным, чтоб так подумать. Опять-таки вы правильно заметили: ''...скорее, фольклорный персонаж, к которому косвенно отсылают, намекая на чью-то неосведомлённость или оторванность от городской цивилизации". А словари зафиксировали то, что уже существует.

Comment: Кстати, у русских чукчи, у армян - абаранцы. И хотя с абаранцами та же связь что и с чукчами, но в словарях, по-крайне мере, старых, даже эта народность не представлена почему-то. А вот в Викисловаре есть  статья: там тоже приведено такое значение. Хотя Вики официальном признать нельзя.

Comment: Алексадр, а по поводу поговорки что Вы думаете?

Comment: Про татарина? Поговорка возникла не из-за свойств одного из этносов (что он плох), а из исторических реалий: здесь "татарин" символизирует завоевателя, под управлением которого долго жили. "Плохо" в этом отсутствие свободы. То, что поговорка осталась в такой буквальной форме, конечно, ограничивает её применение кругом близко знакомых людей. Кто её понимает, вопринимает просто как метафору (хуже незваного гостя не бывает). Для некоторых российский регионов это часть проблемы преподавания совместной истории (распространённое понятие "монголо-татарского ига" тоже создаёт трудности).

Comment: Про поговорку - это анекдот такой ходил.  Никто, конечно, не ходатайствовал, и менять поговорки никто не собирался. Кстати, в наше время иго было "татаро-монгольское".  А полит-корректность вне всякого сомнения побеждает здравый смысл, что очень печально.